# number of rows of an ft searched view

Tags: xpages

I've a view on which I performed a search. I would like to know how many rows this view has after this search. I tried with `rows = view1.getEntryCount();`

But this gives the number of lines of the "original" view, not the result of my search.

**edit**
The following works but isn't verry efficient.
Any better idea ?

```
productTest=sessionScope.get("product");
landTest=sessionScope.get("country");
var length = view1.getEntryCount();
var entries = view1.getAllEntries();
var i = 0;
var rows = 0;
var currentEntry = entries.getFirstEntry();
while(i < length){
land = currentEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(0);
prod = currentEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(1);
if (land == landTest & prod == productTest)
    {
    rows++;
    }
currentEntry = entries.getNextEntry();
i++;
}
viewScope.queryString = rows;   `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on my blog. Try if if it still works:

> var entryCount = viewData.getEntryCount();
>
> var viewControl = getComponent( 'viewControlId' );
>
> var rowCount = viewControl.getRowCount();
>
> // If search is active -> rowcount, else entrycount
>
> var count = ( viewControl.getDataSource().getSearch() ) ? rowCount : entryCount;

Comment: Tommy, Is there a way to "walk" trough the view result after the search this way for example if I want all entries of column 1 ?

Comment: When you have a handle (e.g. a variable called viewControl) on the ViewPanel, you can use this to get the NotesView object: viewControl.getDataSource().getView()

From there you should be able to loop the entries like you would in LotusScript (getFirstEntry...). I think that you only get the filtered entries.

Answer (score 0):

please try

`rows = view1.getrowlines`

Comment: this always gives as result 1 , but there are more rows in the view after the search